# How to use dynamic reference in Firebase cloud functions?

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I need to check every user's confirmed orders node for database write to trigger notification to specific user.
How do I get the list of UID and check for database write in the node?

Database reference is similar to the text below

users/{userid}/confirmed_orders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the users information by using the following query.

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("User");
        ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d("Success", dataSnapshot.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("fail", databaseError.toString());
            }
        };
        mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

Here you will get all the child nodes of all the users which is very high and may lead to performance issues.